# Sugestions about file storage in Amazon AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm developing a Asp.Net MVC project that will be hosted in Amazon AWS, but I have some questions about storage of the client's files. The documentation from Amazon is not clear to me and I'm looking for some directions and experiences here.

1 - each client have a few files with low space disk requirements, low update frequency but very high access frequency (like brand image and even sensitive files like certificates). Is appropriate to storage this files in app_data folder in web server?

2 - the most critical to me are sensitive documents (from hundreds to dozen of thousands per client, most like xml signed files). This files has a medium read access frequency but a very high demand for creation. One solution I found is MongoDB, wich give me some freedom to manage the storage policy and allow me a external backup easy, but I'm not sure about that. Other options are to use the Amazon Storage and handle all this files and GBs in there with a lot of folders or maybe use a regular database and save the files as xml or bin.

My concerns are about the amount of data, the security and the reliable in case of disaster as most of this documents has legal value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could, but storing them locally, violates the shared nothing architecture and would limit your scaling options. Amazon S3 is a good option here. You can set some files public and serve them direct from s3 (or with cloudfront) and keep other private and provide access via signed urls.
2. Again, you can put the files on s3 and make them private. You will still probably store references to the files in your database. Generally its not a great idea to store large blob files in a database since they are often not well optimized to access them.

Comment: The only thing to add here is: Please use password protected certificates only if you intend to store them on a server not under your physical control (even otherwise it is a good idea).

Comment: Another option would be to store all files encrypted with a password given at app startup.

Comment: The client certificates are required to sign the xml files and are part of an external webservice authenticate method. I know it's not ideal but my idea is to store them with a password stored in another location. As far I know that's the best I can do in this situation.